# Finding joint CDF of 2 dependent random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let **X~U([0,1])** and **Y=X**, find the CDF $ $ **$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)$**. Here is my attempt:

$$F_{(X,Y)}(x,y)=P({{X\le x} \cap {Y\le y}})$$
$Since \; \mathbf {Y=X} \; we \; have$
$$P({{X\le x} \cap {X\le y}})=$$
$Let \; \mathbf {m = min\{x,y}\}, \; thus$
$$P({{X\le m} \cap {X\le m}})= P({X\le m})=m$$
$While \; 0 \le x,y \le 1$

I know this is wrong as I have found the (possibly) correct (partial) solution elsewhere, but I don't understand why that is the case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the other solution?

Comment: ${min\{x,y}\}^2 \; while \; 0 \le x,y \le 1\\$ In the other solution the person never get's rid of Y

Comment: Then they are wrong. What is the source?

Comment: So my solution is actually correct, it's simply ${min\{x,y}\}$, without the squared? The solution is from a classmate, so not very credible. However, he seems to have a better understanding of the material than me, so I assumed I must be wrong. (have been banging my head to the wall for over an hour not understanding what I'm doing wrong)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is $Y = X$, I believe your solution is right.

If the problem is $X,Y$ are i.i.d., then the solution should be $P(X \leq x, Y \leq y) = xy$.